# Leave something vs. forget something

Tags: word-usage, differences

Can you **forget** something somewhere?

I expect that much more common is

> I have *left* my book at home.

But, based on other languages where it is quite common (and based on the fact that I somehow feel an *intention* hidden under the *I have left*), can you also use (in general, or GB/US/CA/AU specific) the following form?

> I have *forgotten* my book at home.

If a pupil says the first sentence (with *leave*) in school, will the teacher interpret it as

> I have *intentionally* left my book at home.

or

> I have *accidentally* left my book at home.

?

Comment: It sounds idiomatically quite foreign, to my British ear. You may care to read the comment I have made to @Robusto.

Comment: It sounds so very idiomatic to me, yet a bunch of people are telling me it is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using *forget* in the context of articles you have accidentally left somewhere, especially informally.

If you say

> I forgot my book at home.

nobody will give your usage a second's thought. They'll simply understand that you don't have your book, and why.

It's also shorter and less fussy than saying you "accidentally left your book at home," which may smack of over-explanation.

Remember, it's informal, so you might not want to use it in up-register situations. But it's how people talk in real life.

As for whether there is some "hidden intention" in using present perfect instead of simple past, I can think of none. Either could be used, and nuances would be conveyed with context or vocal modulation.

**later**

I don't know where you get the idea that one version is more intentional than the other, but I can assure you as a native speaker of English that such a connotation doesn't exist.

Comment: And my second question - if I say "I have left my book at home", is there a hidden intention, or is it completely neutral?

Comment: I think I may accept your answer - would you please also think about the second half (about the intention in *I have left something somewhere*)?

Comment: @HonzaZidek: So added.

Comment: Now I am wondering if you are just pulling my leg or if I have expressed my question so badly :) I meant if there is a "hidden intention" in using the **word** *left* instead of *forgotten*, not in using the present perfect tense!

Comment: No joke. It never even occurred to me that that could be your source of concern, so that in itself should reassure you that this is not an issue.

Comment: Well, when I hear "I have left" I sometimes feel *the leaving* as the intentional activity of the subject of the sentence. When I read the Merriam-Webster definition (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave) it sounds more like intentional then accidental.

Comment: I dont know where you get that notion, but I can assure you as a native speaker of English that such a connotation doesn't exist.

Comment: If you find time to modify your answer with this. It otherwise sounds ok to be accepted.

Comment: I had been searching internet before I asked the question. The idea of intention behind usage of "leave" is present in many discussions, e.g. here: http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/96189-Usage-of-forget "'I forgot my book', 'I left my book at home' are common. Of course, they have potentially different meanings, because there is nothing in the second sentence to indicate that you didn't do it on purpose."

Comment: Other links: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/forget-or-leave, http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic12067.html  say that it is *not* correct to use *I forgot my book at home*.

Comment: @Honza: There are things you tolerate from uneducated speakers (including children) and people who are speaking in a hurry or casually or whatever. You don't expect them to speak like pedants every waking minute of their lives (only pedants do that). What I mean when I say it's OK to say "I forgot my book on the bus" is that everyone will know what you mean, and noöne will get upset about it. As a linguistic crime, it's about at the level of crossing the street a second after the light says not to, but there's still time to cross.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Hi, *I left my book at home* can mean either on purpose or accidently. Accident: *I left my book at home, darn it. I wanted to bring it* versus on purpose: *I left my book at home. I'm not studying today.* many times individual sentences cannot encode everything the speaker wants to say. You have to rely on context and perceived  speaker's intention.

Answer (score 2):

One definition of *forget* is to *inadvertently leave behind* (OED). Notice *inadvertently*.

And yes you can indicate where using a prepositional phrase, whether it's *at home*, *on the bus*,  or anywhere else. Apparently the prepositional phrase refers to the location of the forgotten object (as opposed to where the person was when they forgot the object).

For an early usage (1611) see the King James Bible

> When thou cuttest down thine harvest in thy field, and hast forgot a sheaf in the field, thou shalt not go again to fetch it: (Deuteronomy 24:19).

Using modern spelling it's

> ...have forgot a sheaf in the field, you shall not go again to fetch it.

It's clear the shief was forgotten (left behind) *in the field* because the verse says don't go back and get (fetch) it.

[One example sentence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forget)  from the *Oxford dictionary online* is interesting:

> She almost forgot to bring her cell phone at the top of the kitchen counter but luckily she remembered it.

To me this sounds a little disconcerting  because the phone (1) was not actually forgotten, and (2) the prepositional phrase gives such an exact location of where the the "almost-forgotten phone" was–but no longer is!

Comment: The last example sounds strange... "She forgot **to bring** her phone at ..."?

Comment: Yeah I know it sounds strange, I said 'disconcerting'. I'm not comfortable with the sentence. I added a link to Oxford dictionary online (ODO) where you can find the sentence  under 'more example sentences'.