# 'to forget' (usage)

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I've always thought 'forget something somewhere', i.e. with an adverbial of place is wrong usage but recently came across a sentence in a PET book which says. 'I forgot my jacket at Tom's place' and am tempted to consider it a misprint or something. is it actually wrong to say 'gorget sth in a place'?
thanks!
John

Comment: The use case you describe is pretty common usage, however, even if it is wrong. I'm not sure what PET books are, but if it's a reference or text book then it would be a misprint, but otherwise I'd say it was just being informal.

Comment: it sounds colloquial and nonstandard to me. https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22I+forgot+my+jacket+at%22&biw=664&bih=435&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz0IDu8Y3MAhXNa5oKHawnBb0Q_AUICygG&dpr=2

Comment: @Elian - I agree, it is more heard than written though.

Comment: PET (acronym for Preliminary English test) is the B1 level of the battery of Cambridge exams (others include, First Certificate, Proficiency, etc). The book I am talking about is supposed to be a reference book with a number of sample exams and I would've expected a textbook like that to include sentences in perfectly standard English, only.

Comment: @JuanCarlos https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forgot+my+keys+at%2Cleft+my+keys+at%2Cforgot+my+keys+in%2Cleft+my+keys+in%2Cforgot+my+keys+on%2Cleft+my+keys+on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleft%20my%20keys%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20my%20keys%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20my%20keys%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What exactly is "wrong" with that sentence? I forgot to put petrol in the car. (the car is going to run out of petrol) He forgot to post the letter (the letter wasn't posted) Somebody forgot  their jacket (the jacket is still here) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forgot+his+keys%2Cforgets+his+keys%2C+had+forgotten+his+keys&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforgot%20his%20keys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforgets%20his%20keys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20forgotten%20his%20keys%3B%2Cc0 variations of "forget keys" seem pretty common to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, "***[to forget](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forget)***", but I think it is a common mistake, expecially among non natives:

> - You cannot use forget if you want to mention the place where you have left something. ***I've left my book at home***. NOT "I’ve forgotten my book at home."

(OLD)

***To [Leave](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave)***  (not take):

> - to not take something or someone with you when you go, either ​intentionally or by ​accident:
>   *Hey, you've left ​your ​keys on the ​table.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Oh! In India we use this often. During my school days, if I don't do the homework, I would say, "Mam, I finished the homework, but I've forgotten my note at home" as a lame excuse. Nobody corrected me.

Comment: But why is this a mistake? It is like, when you leave the house, you don't remember to take the item and after reaching your destination it strikes you that you actually forgot to take that item with you and you also know that the item is actually present in the house. In this case why shouldn't one say "I have forgotten to take the item from home"?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan - that is the real question.

Comment: Yes. That is the question. Is it just wrong usage or is there a reason why one shouldn't say like that?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286690/leave-something-vs-forget-something

Comment: Ah! The person cannot forget the item. The person can forget to take the item.

Comment: The original wording is perfectly idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks The fact that it's perfectly idiomatic doesn't necessarily mean it is standard... http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic55702.html

Comment: Actually, it does, by any reasonable definition of "standard".

Comment: Is this answer not correct? Why has some one down voted this?