# One more question on the usage of "forget"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I've recently seen questions about the usage of "forget something somewhere". 
The answer, as suggested in [Leave something vs. forget something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286690/leave-something-vs-forget-something) is that the construction is commonly used and acceptable.

Actually reliable resources such as the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/forget-or-leave)  and the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forget) , for instance, clearly state that in the above mentioned construction the verb "leave" should be used instead of  "forget".

I am aware that the construction with forget is common and  that it is grammatically correct, but I don't understand why dictionaries and grammars warn against this usage.

Why is the construction " forget something somewhere"  considered "incorrect"?

***EDIT***: I don't think that this question is a duplicate as Mr. Hot Licks suggests. There is not the answer I am looking for in the other question.

Comment: Saying that A "should be used" in preference to B is not saying that B is wrong.

Comment: I agree, and I used inverted commas to say that. But the cited reference is clear about its usage. You should use "leave".

Comment: Cambridge and, more particularly, Oxford are very fussy in how they interpret "standards" of English grammar (in part because they are two of the best-known purveyors of "standards", and they want to maintain their dominance of the "industry").  They tend to be very "prescriptivist" in their interpretations.

Comment: Is this your personal opinion or can you provide evidence that the two mentioned dictionaries are not reliable in terms of standards and usage?

Comment: I didn't say they weren't reliable -- quite the opposite.  However, they adopt a very strict, prescriptivist view of the language, and in that regard they are "out of step" with most speakers of English.

Comment: Ok, so your answer is that it is a "dictionary specific issue", but also in that case why do they recommend this usage, I guess there must be a reason for that, however disputable it may be.

Comment: @Hot Licks The reason those dictionaries state what they do, is surely because this is a totally non-idiomatic use of *forget*. I have never heard anyone say anything like *I forgot my book at home (and hence I don't have it with me)*. Maybe I have not been listening properly to English spoken around the world for the last 7 decades, but I don't recall ever hearing it. And nor does my wife, who is a Malaysian with English as her first language.

Comment: @WS2 - I've lived in the US for nearly 47 years, and I would probably not notice if someone said "I forgot my book at home" -- I might even say it myself.  There is absolutely nothing non-idiomatic about it.

Comment: The reason the idiom is used is because it's useful.  Saying "I left my book at home" doesn't state that I forgot it -- the "leaving" may have been intentional.  Saying "I forgot my book" doesn't say where it is, which may be a significant point.  Saying "I forgot my book.  I left it at home." seems pretty redundant.  "I forgot my book at home" is clear, concise, and easily understood -- there's no logical reason to object to it.  (But this was all hashed over already in the duplicate question.)

Comment: @WS2 Nonsense. This is such a common usage in North America and Australia that the prescriptivists have lost, and are condemned to turn in their graves beneath headstones with stuffy epitaphs unidiomatic to living, warmblooded ears.

Comment: @modulus0 Whether or not such a thing can be considered *standard English* is an entirely separate matter. I don't even know of any person who actually says it, and would be interested to meet one, if you are able to arrange an introduction.

Comment: @WS2 Don't take this the wrong way, but if you've been around for 7 decades, you almost certainly have a very different view of what constitutes standard English than the majority/mean/median of its speakers. Again, if you were to speak with native English speakers in North America or Australia younger than 30, you would neither contest that this is idiomatic nor that it _will_ be an accepted usage in the next edition of the Oxford.

Comment: @modulus0 I will ask my eleven-year-old grandson when I next see him. And I shall be flabbergasted if he recognises it as something his chums would say. We are regularly in contact with youngsters and I've never heard it. Had our lad said it, I would have corrected him, and pointed out that it was not good English - as tiresome middle-class parents and grandparents are inclined to do. I have lived in Australia but that was a long time ago. But I am amazed I have not heard it or seen it anywhere online, or on a TV channel.

Comment: @WS2 consider the possibility that you heard it being casually uttered, (*Bugger, forgot my umbrella on the  bus*) knew exactly what the speaker meant, and then thought nothing more of it. To say you have never heard in conversation is unlikely, have you never spoken to speakers whose first language was not English?

Comment: @Saturna  'I forgot my book at home' is probably a contraction of 'I forgot to bring my book when I left home this morning...'. I think it is incorrectly used because *forgetting* refers to a mental activity, not a physical one. So, taken literally, the first sentence just means 'I wasn't *thinking* of my book [when I was] at home', or 'I couldn't *remember* my book [when I was] at home'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes I concede that I could well have heard a non-native speaker say it, long forgotten about. When my daughter was about 7 she wrote a story about an encounter with a snake. One sentence read *The snake hisssed* -spelt with three s's. It is something I recall with affection, but that does not mean there is a case for saying that since one little girl once spelt the word that way, that it has any claim to be a possible spelling. If we are going to include within the site's remit every possible incorrect use of English by non-native speakers, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think this is an interesting question, what would you answer  if one of your students asked you?

Comment: @Josh61 I wouldn't make such a great fuss. I think it's fine, it's grammatical and it's totally comprehensible. There are much worse slurs on the English language than someone saying they forgot their umbrella on the train. Btw the question is perfectly legitimate, but it's been asked before.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - I think OP is asking why two sources are so prescriptive about it, not about the more or less accepted usage. –

Comment: @Mari-LouA - actually the Cambridge link refers to:  (“Forget or leave ?” from English Grammar Today © Cambridge University Press.) That's my University :)

Comment: @Josh61 Likewise a grammar book is starting base for a learner, it helps the learner, sometimes tremendously but you can not learn to "speak" a foreign language just by reading chapters in a grammar book.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I may agree, buy ***why*** Cambridge and Oxford agree on this pont? That's is probably the issue.

Comment: Because it is *good* English, and because they want to maintain standards.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes "good English" probably  Julie Carter comment explains why.

Answer (score 4):

The remark about when  to use to use *leave* instead of *forget* refers only to locatives, like *at home*.

- *I forgot my license,* but not **I left my license.*
- *I left my license **at home**,* but not **I forgot my license **at home**.*

*Forget* has no implicit reference to a place, but *leave* does.

*I forgot something somewhere*, however, is vague enough not to be ungrammatical.
Especially when *somewhere* isn't a real locative, but merely a metaphorical reference to a process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you basically agree with what the dictionaries suggest about this specific usage of forget.

Comment: *I forgot my license at home* is totally grammatical for me, but with different meaning to *I left my license at home*. The former is always accidental, whereas the latter may be either accidental or intentional. *Forget* used thus is simply the antonym of *get*, a meaning which it has had since Old English.

Comment: But I take it, John L., that you mean something like: *I forgot my book on the bus (but the driver noticed I'd left it and shouted to me)*. That sounds vaguely idiomatic. But "Where is your book?" Answer "Oh, I forgot it on the bus" certainly doesn't. It has to be *I left it on the bus*, doesn't it?

Comment: @Anonym Are you able to tell us more about which idiolect of English you speak?

Comment: @WS2 I speak Canadian English, from the West Coast.

Comment: I prefer this answer to that on the linked question because this answer points out that "*[f]orget* has no implicit reference to a place, but *leave* does".